# Помогите доделать ajax  с setinterval и clearinterval

Tags: setinterval, ajax, html, clearinterval, javascript

Как только обработчик получит ответ в 1 необходимо выключить setinterval...
но не понимаю как все в одно целое собрать

```
    $(".status_domain").click(function(){
        var action_id = $(this).attr('id').substring(20);
        alert("action_id="+action_id);
        primer=1;
        setTimeout($.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../ajax/obr_form_gen.php",
        data:"action=check_domain&id="action_id,
                success:function(qwer){                
                if(qwer==1){
                    $('#true_domain_confirm_'+action_id).show();
                }
                },
                            }), 1000);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не вижу, где у Вас здесь setInterval (только setTimeout, а он и так один раз выполняется), но в случае setInterval логика следующая:

```
var intervalID = setInterval(function(){ ..какие-то действия.. } , 1000);
```

Когда какое-то условие выполнено, вызывается:

```
clearInterval(intervalID)
```

И код перестаёт выполняться. В вашем случае clearInterval нужно вызывать внутри условия:

```
           if(qwer==1){
                $('#true_domain_confirm_'+action_id).show();
            }
```

При этом заменив setTimeout на setInterval.